# Opening Port on Apache2

Tags: python, apache

I am running a digital ocean droplet with the wordpress image. This appears to be running apache2 as the frontend server.

I want to run a second server behind this to serve up flask applications on a different domain, essentially sharing the same droplet.

I cannot for the life of me get this to work.

I've added this to the `ports.conf`: `Listen 8079`
Then I've added this to the `sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:8079>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm trying to run a simple python server to test but I cannot seem to get it to start because Python claims the port is in use. I can reconfigure the ports being loaded but the same thing happens. I assume apache is reserving this port.

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8079`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that all of the above was unnecessary.

Really all that had to be done was to set the firewall to allow the port

`sudo ufw allow 8079/tcp`

Now any server listening to 8079 will respond.